# Are SCJP 6 and OCJP both same?

Tags: java, scjp

Are both `SCJP 6` and `OCJP 6` exams same? I am going to write OCJP 6 exam this month end but I am preparing SCJP 6 book by Kathy Seirra.

And for practice I am preparing Kathy seirra's `"OCP Java SE 6 programmer study guide"`.
is it ok?

I am confusing with this words `"SCJP 6" , "OCJP 6", "OCP Java SE 6 Programmer"`. Are those same?

If same why these many different names?

Thank you in advance?  please guide me .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the question sets used for both exams are identical and the Sierra/Bates book is good preparation material. In order to prepare even better, I would advise to take some mock tests first. There is a large number of free ones on the net.

EDIT: as to the naming ambiguities - the certificate was issued by Sun Microsystems and called [SCJP - **Sun Certified Java Programmer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCJP#Sun_Certified_Java_Programmer_.28SCJP.29). After Oracle acquired Sun in early 2010 (the agreement has been signed in 2009), the certificate has been officially renamed to **Oracle Certified Professional Java SE Programmer** or OCPJP. Many people continue to call it SCJP though.

Comment: Renamed SCJP to OCJP, isn't it? I don't think there are two exams now.

Comment: @thinksteep You're right - there is no way to actually become a SCJP if you aren't one already :)

Answer (score 1):

Different names because of "ownership" - used to be Sun Certified Java Programmer, now Oracle Certified Java Programmer.

Answer (score 1):

As of i know so far, the only one difference is that drap-and-drop type of questions are not available anymore in OCPJP exam verion

Answer (score 0):

Well SCJP6 and OCJP6 is basically the same exam. You cannot take the SJCP anymore as Oracle took over Sun and their exams.

The test changed a little bit. For the preperation I have seen lots of complete the code samples, which I haven't seen on the actual exam. They changed the testing provider from Prometric to PearsonVUE as well.